# Как добавить обработчик события на кнопку в андроид в фрагменте?

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-on-click, onclicklistener

Подскажите, как я могу добавить обработчик к кнопке на фрагменте, что бы он работал.
Я пробовал добавить обработчик на самом фрагменте в методе onCreateView() перед тем как возращается вью, но получаю ошибку, нашел вот этот туториал, 
https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/176-urok-106-android-3-fragments-vzaimodejstvie-s-activity.html
здесь юзается фрагменты с пакета android.app.Fragment а не из android.support.v4.app.Fragment, так вообще приложение стало вылетать без обЪяснения причины.

Подскажите как реализовать эту логику правильно. Прилагая класс фрагмента для наглядности:

```
public class RegistrationNameSecondNameEmailFragment extends Fragment {

    private UserModel user;

    private EditText etRegistraionName;
    private EditText etRegistrationSecondName;
    private EditText etRegistrationEmail;
    private TextView tvRegistrationNameEnter;
    private Button btnRegistrationNext;

    public RegistrationNameSecondNameEmailFragment() {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_registration_name_second_name_email, container, false);

        etRegistraionName = view.findViewById(R.id.etRegistraionName);
        etRegistrationSecondName = view.findViewById(R.id.etRegistrationSecondName);
        etRegistrationEmail = view.findViewById(R.id.etRegistrationEmail);
        tvRegistrationNameEnter = view.findViewById(R.id.tvRegistrationNameEnter);
        btnRegistrationNext = view.findViewById(R.id.btnRegistrationNext);

        user = new UserModel();

        btnRegistrationNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                System.out.println("Check");
                user.setName(etRegistraionName.getText().toString());
                user.setSecondName(etRegistrationSecondName.getText().toString());
                user.setEmail(etRegistrationEmail.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Стек ошибки добавьте. В вашем коде явных ошибок не наблюдается.

Comment: @woesss, лог к сожалению прикрепить не могу, приложение не вылетает, но обработчик не срабатывает сейчас. Код остался тот же, что происходит не могу понять.

Comment: Не работает - в смысле вы в логах не находите строку `"Check"`? Где-то когда-то слышал, что на Андроиде `System.out.print...` может не работать. Попробуйте что-то другое: `Log`, `Toast`, изменить текст на экране...

Comment: @woesss, Я изменил на лог вот так вот `Log.d("Test: ", "Check");`, но все равно не выводит, плюс пробовал вывести с помощью Toast, тоже безуспешно...

Comment: Тогда могу только предположить что: либо вы в процессе экспериментов создали и показываете другой фрагмент с такой же или той же разметкой, но обработчика в нём нет; либо у вас `Instant Run` чудит - попробуйте сделать ребилд проекта, не поможет - отключить `Instant Run` в настойках на время, ну или совсем, если скорость сборки и запуска вас устроит.

Answer (score 0):

На тему библиотеки support - вы или во всем приложении используете только классы из support, или только из основной либы. Начнете мешать - будет вылетать. Потому что там не только фрагменты отличаются, но и FragmentMAnager разный, например. У активити есть 2  метода разных - getFragmentManager и getSupportFragmentManager. Суть, я надеюсь, борлее менее понятно передал.

По поводу вашего конкретного случая - учитесь ставить брейкпоинты и отлаживать пошагово программу. Без этого далеко не уйти. Ставьте брейкпоинты на первой строчке onCreateView и на первой строчке слушателя, смотрите попадаете ли вы туда вообще.

Ну и единственное, что могу еще предположить - возможно вам нужно присвоение слушателя и все findViewById перенести в метод onViewCreated. Там точно есть какие-то тонкости, которых уже за давностью лет не упомню, может они приводят к проблемам